# Doxygen put HTML tag after a @snippets command

Tags: html, command, alias, doxygen

I have created an ALIAS to embedd a `\snippet` into a HTML `<div></div>`

```
ALIASES += "snippetLang{2}=<div id='\1' class='snippetcontent'> \snippet \2 </div>"
```

Then I use the alias like this:

```
@snippetLang{CS,ExampleForm.cs OnShow example}
```

The parameters expands fine but since snippet's second parameter spands to the end of the line, the `</div>` tag will be included.

```
<div id='CS' class='snippetcontent'> \snippet ExampleForm.cs OnShow example </div>
```

The `\snippet` command will now look for the reference "`OnShow example </div>`" instead of only the "`OnShow example`"

Is there any way to make doxygen expand the command where the `\snippet \1` is on its own line, like this?

```
<div id='CS' class='snippetcontent'>
\snippet ExampleForm.cs OnShow example
</div>
```

The Doxygen version is 1.8.14

Comment: Did you try to place `^^` before the `</div>`? This is to force a line break. Please also specify the doxygen version you are using (does influence the line break in an ALIAS).

Comment: @albert I added the Doxygen version and your solution worked. If you write a proper answer I can mark it as the solution. However I ran into next problem and will post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doxygen documentation (1.8.15):

> ALIASES This tag can be used to specify a number of aliases that act
>   as commands in the documentation. An alias has the form: name=value For
>   example adding "sideeffect=@par Side Effects:\n" will allow you to put
>   the command \sideeffect (or @sideeffect) in the documentation, which
>   will result in a user-defined paragraph with heading "Side Effects:".
>   You can put \n's in the value part of an alias to insert newlines (in
>   the resulting output). You can put ^^ in the value part of an alias to
>   insert a newline as if a physical newline was in the original file.
>   When you need a literal { or } or , in the value part of an alias you
>   have to escape them by means of a backslash (), this can lead to
>   conflicts with the commands{ and } for these it is advised to use
>   the version @{ and @} or use a double escape (\{ and \})

The version:

```
ALIASES += "snippetLang{2}=<div id='\1' class='snippetcontent'> \snippet \2 ^^</div>"
```

will work for the version 1.8.14 and up

the version

```
ALIASES += "snippetLang{2}=<div id='\1' class='snippetcontent'> \snippet \2 \n</div>"
```

will work for the versions from before 1.8.14